# iPad memory used if far higher than sum of all App's memory usage

Tags: ios, ipad

I've got two iPad Air, one 64GB the other 16GB. Both on iOS 7.1.2.

On my 64GB iPad, the sum of memory used by all Apps very closely matches the memory used figure above the list of Apps (40.3GB vs. 41.2GB). On the 16GB iPad, the sum of memory used by all Apps amounts to ~720MB but memory used is reported as 7GB.

How do I find out what is using the ~6GB? It can't be iOS itself, is it? I guess, I would expect to see a ~6GB difference between the numbers on the 64GB iPad, too, if it was iOS.

Comment: I have an iPhone 4(iOS 7.1.2) and iPad 3(iOS 8+). Both lose storage space. Several times, I have had to re-install the operating system on both. The iPhone loses the most, more often.
I checked the settings and iCloud lists. The iCloud list showed two apps that had outdated amounts of file space. I deleted the iCloud backup thinking the existing backup was that size. I also deleted the apps from iCloud backup. Still, the apps are allotted several gigabytes space. I'm sure I'll regain the space next o/s installation but the thing is inconvenient. Poor storage space accounting is the culprit, in

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your iPad is connected to the computer, click on the Device and look at the bottom of the screen. There is a bar that shows how much data each category is using.  What is the size of the "other data" category?

Your iPad stores not only the Apps but there is a lot of stuff like:
Browser cache,
Mail cache,
Mail messages,
Mail attachments,
Safari's Reading List,
iTunes Backups,
Game data,
Saved data files,
Call history,
Notes,
Media,
Voice memos,
etc.

To see what is using the memory space on iPad: Settings->General->Usage

In this list: All installed Apps are listed, tap on any App to see the actual App size and the amount of documents and data used by this App.

To delete this data, you have to delete the App, restart your device (press and hold Home and Sleep until you see the Apple logo) and reinstall it from the AppStore.

Comment: Thanks. I will check with iTunes later today. The "sum of memory used by Apps" was calculated with the data shown by Settings->General->Usage.

Comment: Keep in mind that list doesn't show everything. The items listed in the answer above are not included in the Usage list on iOS 7 (except for Mail, and Media, which is split into Music, Video and Sounds).

Comment: I checked with iTunes, and the "other data" category was about 5GB, so the missing memory was assigned there. After backing up the iPad that memory was given back, so that the amount of free memory now is what I expected. I don't know what data it was that got freed; I didn't delete neither apps nor app data. I learnt that backing up will also do some cleanup whatsoever. Thanks for the hint.